# Do single quotes treat backslashes as special in bash scripting?

Tags: regex, bash, terminal, double-quotes, single-quotes

From what I've read [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#WHITESPACEREF) it says that *"Within single quotes, every special character except ' gets interpreted literally"*.  So, I thought that the backslash ("\") also gets interpreted literally.

But, then when I try to use it in an alias, it somehow still gets interpreted as a special character:

`alias somefolder='cd /Some\ path/with\ spaces/'`

...still works?

And yet this doesn't:

`alias somefolder='cd /Some path/with spaces/'`

This surprises me, because I thought the whole point of the single quotes was supposed to be for laziness, i.e. for when you aren't expanding any variables with the `$` (because that would require double quotes).

I really doubt that the tldp source is wrong, so is there a better way of explaining this?  Thanks.

Comment: nothing to do with the quotes. it has to do with the alias expansion, which is quite literal of the string *value*. put the quotes around just the path.

Comment: ... which is one of many reasons why shell functions should be used instead of aliases. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/080

Comment: still....I am further baffled by this:  `alias somefolder='cd '/Some path/with spaces/''` doesn't work, as i said in the question.  However, from the command line, `cd '/Some path/with spaces/'` *does* work?

Comment: ...so if the the alias expansion strips off the single quotes, then why doesn't it work to put another set of single quotes around the path name after `cd`?

Answer (score 4):

That's because alias will be expanded by shell, in the process the single quotes will be removed. So after alias expansion you will just have

```
cd /Some path/with spaces/
```

remaining which would fail as you have said.

But while you are using `\` to escape the spaces, after expanding the alias (and removing single quotes) the shell will have the following to operate on:

```
cd /Some\ path/with\ spaces/
```

which would work as expected.

Comment: To be more precise, the quotes have already been removed when the alias gets created.

Comment: Thanksfor your answer.  However, something is still peculiar about this, please see my comment on my question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, but the alias you are building is putting out your single quoted var to the `cd` command, which is choking on your

```
cd /Some path/with spaces/
```

because `cd` doesn't know what to do with the space, not your bash.

When you add the `\` to the string as in

```
'cd /Some\ path/with\ spaces/'
```

it is `cd` that is interpreting the `\`, not the bash which is merely a messenger.